# How can I install hulahop

Tags: software-installation, compiling, python

I cloned [hulahop](http://git.sugarlabs.org/hulahop) via git and I'd like to use it and try to run [this](http://wiki.laptop.org/go/Sugar_Code_Snippets#WebView) example.

I have a problem to find out how to build and install it. I also tried to install it with `apt-get` but I don't have this package available.

[Xubuntu 10.04]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(First things first: I have never used nor installed hulahop, what follows is generic, based on glancing over the source tree.)

---

To get this straight, there are basically two ways to install something in a Debian(-derived) distribution:

1. **the clean way**: via a `.deb` package and some tool like `apt-get`, `aptitude`, `dpkg`, you can *build them yourself* or semi-self by using tools like `checkinstall` (for example, there are probably others); this enables you to use your distribution's tools to *remove* them and you're thus save from cluttering up your system, what is the danger of...
2. **the manual way**, i.e., using whatever is provided in the sources to *compile and install* it yourself.  The important part is choosing where to install it to, usually called "prefix". (A prefix of `/usr/local` or `$HOME` or `$HOME/.local` can be used to separate manually installed packages from the distribution's packages.*****)

So, given you chose (2.), you have to look [at the cloned sources](http://git.sugarlabs.org/hulahop/mainline/trees/master), where you'll find:

- [`autogen.sh`](http://git.sugarlabs.org/hulahop/mainline/blobs/master/autogen.sh), a three-line shell script that calls `autoreconf`, part of the [GNU build system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autotools), which if run successfully (i.e., you have the necessary build tools, e.g. `autotools` or `build-essenstial` packages, not sure about these) creates a `configure` script. The `autogen.sh` script then calls `./configure "$@"`, i.e., it creates a `Makefile` tailored to your system that is used to compile the sources, in the classical `./configure && make && make install` way). *If you want to change the prefix*, pass `--prefix=/the/prefix/you/want` to `configure` (or to `autogen.sh` since it passes the argument to `configure`, via `$@`) -- this is the manual way
- a [`debian/`](http://git.sugarlabs.org/hulahop/mainline/trees/master/debian) folder, that contains what is needed to create a `.deb` package -- the clean way!
  When you find this in sources, it can be worthwhile to *check if someone already built a `deb` package*, since it's strong evidence for this. [Googling "hulahop debian"](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=hulahop%20debian) reveals a [Debian package](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/python-hulahop) and [an Ubuntu package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sugar-hulahop) `sugar-hulahop`.  You could use these or if you still prefer to install the newest sources, you could [try (again) what was told you here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188169/how-can-i-install-hulahop/8188339#8188339) and ask a question including a specific error if it fails.

(***** If you chose a prefix, be sure to *tell every involved party*, i.e., adjust `$PATH` if you want your shell to know where to find an executable, do [whatever is needed for python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/) to know where to `import` something from, etc.)

Comment: I have chosen the `autogen.sh` way, but `sh autogen.sh` has problem with `libxul` package and my `apt-get` has problem to install it `no installation candidate`.

Comment: I don't  know Ubuntu's `apt`-iness, but if there's an `apt-cache` (there probably is) `apt-cache search libxul` should  [tell you some packages that might be the `libxul` you need](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libxul).  Try `libxul-dev`, it should install the needed binary lib, too, and the dev package is what you need to build something using it.

Comment: I have already tried it but can't figure out which file to download and install. 1) I can't see install files for my Ubuntu version 2) I can't see any download links of deb files.

Comment: Sorry, I probably wasn't clear. Try `apt-get install libxul-dev` and on success try `autogen.sh` again.  Repeat with other missing dependencies, using `apt-cache search libwhatever` to find the packages in your distribution's repository that might be the dependencies. (You can also try `apt-get build-dep sugar-hulahop` to install all build dependencies of the `.deb` package.)

Comment: Thank you, but this is what I [tried](http://pastebin.com/gMcWwhEs)

Comment: You could consider updating your question with some error output, maybe someone can help.

Comment: Other clean way is `easy-install` or `pip`

Comment: @sr_ installation of `libxul-dev` is solved. I have stuck on [this](http://pastebin.com/VhTTnZnU) now.

Comment: @EirNym `easy_install` is the first thing I tried. But there is no `hulahop` in PyPI

Comment: @sr_ I will accept your general solution and open questions for particular problems.

Comment: @xralf: This could be a workable solution: [Since building sugar under Ubuntu is apparently not supported at the moment](http://wiki.sugarlabs.org/go/Development_Team/Jhbuild/Ubuntu), you could try to set up a Debian Chroot environment ([here's an explanation, but without warranty, just google'd it)](http://wp.me/p5kcU-8U) to **(a)** [use their packages](http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=hulahop) or **(b)** [use the `jhbuild` mechanism, supported on Debian](http://wiki.sugarlabs.org/go/Development_Team/Jhbuild).  HTH!

Comment: (cont.) This could bring in other problems (maybe with X11) but they can probably be solved.  (You could of course also try a Debian virtual machine installation, I've never actually tried the `chroot` way in this particular Ubuntu/Debian setting.)  (Also note [the Debian specific jhbuild notes on the linked wiki](http://wiki.sugarlabs.org/go/Development_Team/Jhbuild/Debian).)