# Make errors when compiling hulahop

Tags: compiling, make, autoreconf

When I cloned [hulahop](http://git.sugarlabs.org/hulahop) I had a [few possibilities](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24935/how-can-i-install-hulahop/24936#24936) to install it.

I have chosen the path with `autogen.sh`

I used commands:

```
$ sh autogen.sh # -> OK
$ ./configure   # -> OK
```

But `make` fails:

```
$ sudo make 2> errors.txt
$ cat errors.txt
hulahop.cpp:28:29: error: pyxpcom/PyXPCOM.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/python2.6/Python.h:8,
                 from hulahop-web-view.h:23,
                 from hulahop.h:23,
                 from hulahop.cpp:31:
/usr/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h:395:1: warning: "HAVE_LONG_LONG" redefined
In file included from /usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.24/nspr/prtypes.h:58,
                 from /usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.24/nscore.h:51,
                 from /usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.24/nsDebug.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.24/nsCOMPtr.h:59,
                 from hulahop.cpp:20:
/usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.24/nspr/prcpucfg.h:807:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /usr/include/python2.6/Python.h:8,
                 from hulahop-web-view.h:23,
                 from hulahop.h:23,
                 from hulahop.cpp:31:
/usr/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h:1031:1: warning: "_POSIX_C_SOURCE" redefined
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:27,
                 from /usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.24/nspr/obsolete/protypes.h:79,
                 from /usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.24/nspr/prtypes.h:517,
                 from /usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.24/nscore.h:51,
                 from /usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.24/nsDebug.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.24/nsCOMPtr.h:59,
                 from hulahop.cpp:20:
/usr/include/features.h:158:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /usr/include/python2.6/Python.h:8,
                 from hulahop-web-view.h:23,
                 from hulahop.h:23,
                 from hulahop.cpp:31:
/usr/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h:1040:1: warning: "_XOPEN_SOURCE" redefined
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:27,
                 from /usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.24/nspr/obsolete/protypes.h:79,
                 from /usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.24/nspr/prtypes.h:517,
                 from /usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.24/nscore.h:51,
                 from /usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.24/nsDebug.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/xulrunner-1.9.2.24/nsCOMPtr.h:59,
                 from hulahop.cpp:20:
/usr/include/features.h:160:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
hulahop.cpp: In function ‘HulahopWebView* hulahop_get_view_for_window(PyObject*)’:
hulahop.cpp:101: error: ‘Py_nsISupports’ has not been declared
hulahop.cpp:112: error: ‘do_GetService’ was not declared in this scope
make[1]: *** [hulahop.lo] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Could you help me with compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `error: pyxpcom/PyXPCOM.h: No such file or directory`

You need [PyXPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/PyXPCOM). It's not [currently in Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=PyXPCOM.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=oneiric&arch=any).

There are a couple of [old PyXPCOM PPAs](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=pyxpcom), you could try them, but both haven't been updated since maverick so they might not work.

Otherwise, [build PyXPCOM from source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_PyXPCOM). But first, check if [PyXPCOMext](http://pyxpcomext.mozdev.org/) (which you can get in binary form) is sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just making system upgrade to maverick and then newer versions later, so if there will be errors with PyXPCOM build in newer versions I will ask new question.